# Laravel - Authorize user to update resource only with foreign key items that belong to same organization as user

Tags: laravel, eloquent, authorization, laravel-authorization

I want to authorize a resource in my Laravel application, so that users can only change a foreign key id only to a value of an item, that belongs to the same organization as the user.

As an example:

A `user` belongs to an `organization` => `user.organization_id`

A `organization` has many `item` objects => `item.organization_id`

Now the `user` wants to update a resource that has some columns and four item columns `item1`,`item2`,`item3`,`item4`.

The `user` should only be allowed to set one of these 4 items with an id of an `item` that belongs to his organization.

I created a Controller and Policy for this case which contains the function

```
// Controller function
public function update(Request $request, ItemToUpdate $item)
    {
        //
    }

// Policy function
public function update(User $user, ItemToUpdate $item)
    {
        //return true;
    }
```

Now my question is: What is the **most performant** way to check if the user is allowed to update the resource with the ids, that are sent in the request.

Of course I could make a DB request for every item and check if `item.organization_id === user.organization_id`, but is this really the most performant and efficient way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way is to create a custom Request and inside authorize method do your checks

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give an example?